# Once a visa got refused to one country, will it affect the visa to another country?

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, new-zealand

I had applied for New Zealand student visa without IELTS in last February. But unfortunately it got rejected. The reason in the rejection letter shows that I haven't answered about the course details. During the embassy interview I was not able to answer few questions. I think that is the reason behind the rejection. After my visa got rejected I had gone for IELTS coaching and gained band score of 6 (L:6 ,R:5.5 ,W:7 ,S:5.5). Now I would like to submit for Canada student visa. Will it get rejected once again ?

Comment: It is probably important to add whether you have a letter of acceptance from a Canadian university/college.

Answer (score 3):

New Zealand is a signatory to the [Five Eyes Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes).  Therefore they will pass the refusal information along to the other members of the affluent Commonwealth, and this will include Canada.

It does not mean your application will be automatically refused by the Canadian authorities, but they will have access to your previous application(s).

The Five Eyes Treaty is generic to all visa applications and has relevance here because of that. If you have questions directly related to student visas, please use [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions) in the future.

Comment: Also all the visa applications I have seen (NZ, AUS) have a question 'Have you been denied a visa to this or another country?' Answer that honestly, and perhaps include copies of your correspondence.